# Can I restrict the formatting of a Powerpoint 2010 document?

Tags: microsoft-office

This is an option in Word (under Review > Protect > Formatting restrictions). However, this option doesn't seem to exist in Powerpoint.

I want users to be able to add content to a Powerpoint template I've created but I need to ensure the formatting does not change.

Can somebody please assist?

Thanks in advance!